# Seletores CSS (H1 - H6 aplicando após p)

Tags: css, html-tags, seletores

Estou em Dúvida de aplicar alguns efeitos no css. Tentei com os seguintes seletores do css:

```
h1+p, h2+p, h3+p, h4+p, h5+p, h6+p {
    margin: 0 0 0.75em 0;
}

h1~p, h2~p, h3~p, h4~p, h5~p, h6~p {
    margin: 0 0 0.75em 0;
}

h1>p, h2>p, h3>p, h4>p, h5>p, h6>p {
    margin: 0 0 0.75em 0;
}

h1 p, h2 p, h3 p, h4 p, h5 p, h6 p {
    margin: 0 0 0.75em 0;
}
```

A ideia é que após digitar a TAG `<h6></h6>` aplique um espaço para digitar a TAG `<p></p>`, dentro de uma estrutura de texto `<div></div>` por exemplo;

Porque já utilizo o espaço entre às TAG's `<p></p>` e só preciso para `<h1><h6>`.

Comment: Podes explicar melhor ? Como assim espaço para digitar uma tag de parágrafo ?

Comment: Bem após de eu digitar, ele automaticamente desse um espaço para o parágrafo: `<h6>Subtitulo</h6>` -Espaço- `<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat dolorum non, ab quisquam consequatur ullam necessitatibus in sit placeat aperiam!</p>`

Comment: São ambas tags com espaçamento após o conteúdo, a única diferença é que as tags `h` definem cabeçalhos e a tag `p` define parágrafos, no mínimo terias que remover o espaçamento das tags `h6` usando `margin:0;` e depois usar `h6+p { margin:.75em 0 0 0; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que houve um engano, os atributos dentro do seletor serão aplicados no parágrafo e não no h1~h6, por isso ao invés de margin bottom o correto seria margin top:

```
h1+p, h2+p, h3+p, h4+p, h5+p, h6+p {
    margin: 0.75em 0 0 0;
}
```

ou então, para ficar mais claro:

```
h1+p, h2+p, h3+p, h4+p, h5+p, h6+p {
    margin-top: 0.75em;
}
```

Documentação sobre combinators: [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp).

Comment: Gostei da Referência, mas ainda não aplicou o efeito, queria fazer na TAG este espaço do que utilizar o style no primeiro `<p></p>`, utilizando o `margin-top` neste caso.

Comment: Perdão, funcionou, estava aplicando uma medida muito baixa, obrigado pela referência.